# Selenium clicks link behind div

Tags: java, selenium

We had a problem on our website, where the Facebook like-button in our fixed top navbar had a 1000px height iframe. It was transparent, but all below it wasn't clickable.

Because of this we came to the point that we want to test, whether it's possible for a user to click links on our website, based on visibility and not blocked by a "div" or something. In my testcase I put a div over a link, for me it isn't clickable but selenium can still click it.

Test.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="under"><a href="index.php">click</a></div>
        <div class="over">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Stylesheet.css

```
.over {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

test.java

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://localhost/test/test.php");
        // driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/hmtl/div[1]/a")).click();

        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("click")), 1, 1).click().build().perform();
    }
}
```

I tried it with `WebDriver` and with `Actions` and with different `findElement(By)` but all clicked the link. Is there an other possibility to test it or is my test-case just wrong?

Comment: Is that link not clickable manually?

Comment: manually it isnt because its blocked by the div, thats the case i wanna test

Comment: Did you try to click it without using `Actions()` interface? Just plain click - `driver.findElement(By.linkText("click")).click();` or does hover on that element help? I feel that if your div really blocks it, click function shouldn't work on that element.

Comment: Yes I tried both ways, Action and plain click separatly, both clicks wasnt blocked.

Comment: Can you add a `&nbsp;` to the over div and see how it behaves?

Comment: @Kapotth What version of Selenium? What version of FF? And are you using synthetic events? I think I have an answer for you but I want to make sure.

Comment: It doesnt work, I already tried to fill the over-div with text, same outcome.

Comment: I use Selenium 2.47.1 and FF 33. I dont know what synthetic events are sorry. All my code used is above.

Comment: When you post HTML please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ to properly format it. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Same thing goes for code... please post it out of an editor so it's properly formatted/indented. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Summary

What you describe is precisely what happens with synthetic events. Use native events. They are available on Chrome and IE, and, according to the [changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG) on versions of Firefox up to 33, and on FF 38. The general method to turn native events on is to set the Selenium capability `"nativeEvents"` to `true`. Moreover, once the driver has been created, you should query this same capability to check whether native events have been turned on, because if there is any problem with turning them on, the driver will turn off native events silently. I don't work with Java (I use Python) so I'm not sure how you would do this with Java but what I've mentioned *is* what you have to do.

Note when Selenium is driving a Chrome browser you can only use native events, not synthetic events: it is not possible to turn them off (trying to turn them off is silently ignored), and Chrome always starts with native events on.

Also note that the changelog itself is sometimes buggy. There are times I used versions of Selenium and FF that the changelog *claims* can do native events but it did not work. (I've used native events with Selenium and FF for many years now. I'm sure it was not an error on my part.)

#### Explanation

Native events trigger events in the browser by simulating what happens when the browser gets an event from the OS. When a browser gets a mouse event from the browser and needs to send it to a DOM element, it will scan the DOM tree and determine which element the user can access at the location of the mouse pointer. So if you trigger an event on an element that is not in fact accessible to the user because it is covered by another element, the covering element will get the event (not the covered one).

Synthetic events are purely internal to the browser. The problem with these events is that they are sent directly to the element you ask Selenium to send them to. So they ignore the case where one element overlaps another. If the element you target is covered by another element and thus would not be clickable by the user, you can still click it.

(A note for those who would wonder why one would want to click on an element which is inaccessible to the user. If the covered element is covered by a *transparent* element, then clicking the covered element can simulate a user attempting to access an element they cannot access. For an extremely common and banal case: the modal dialogs in Bootstrap cover the entire window behind the modal with a backdrop that traps any attempt at clicking outside the modal. There's one extremely common, banal use-case scenario for this. And this is just one.)

#### Background Information

Support for native events in FF is on its way out, and synthetic events are not able to fill the void. There is a bug report [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/813) pointing out the exact problem of overlapping elements but there does not seem to be any hurry to fix it.

The issue is that the Firefox developers removed from Firefox an API that Selenium *happened* to use to provide synthetic events. Removing this API was probably the right call from the point-of-view of the Firefox developers, but something should have been put into place to allow Selenium to continue supporting native events. This did not happen. After a bit of discussion, the [Selenium folks decided](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/selenium-developers/DKnG2lA-KxM/discussion) that since the API was no longer present, then Selenium would flat out stop supporting native events on Firefox. Note that I've not seen any evidence that the Selenium folks ever said to the Firefox developers "Listen guys, we need to be able to acquire a window handle so that we can support native events on Firefox in Selenium." They did not suggest an alternate API or explain to the Firefox developers what this entails for people trying to test whether their applications work on Firefox.

The Selenium developers have been made aware that synthetic events on Firefox just do not cut it because they [don't handle](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/813) overlapping events, [don't generate](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/825) `focus` and `blur` events like real user interaction with a browser does, [do not accurately simulate](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/862) the events generated when an element is removed from the DOM during a `click`. (In all these cases native events correctly simulate what happens when a real user interacts with the browser.)

However, I don't see the Selenium developers putting this on their priority list until users of Selenium start complaining.

Comment: To activate nativeEvents in Java, setup your dirver with:
`FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);`

Comment: True but the `profile` thing is specific to Firefox. There is no such thing as a Chrome profile or an IE profile that you can create in the same way you do `new FirefoxProfile()` and use to enable native events. What I described is the cross-browser way to request native events on FF, Chrome, IE (and presumably any browser that Selenium supports). I run large test suites on FF, Chrome, IE so I try to minimize the browser-specific approaches.